# How to download list of artifacts from maven nexus repository using Java

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a Maven Nexus repository that manages several maven projects.Every time build happens on the specific project we send binaries/snap shots to Nexus.There are several ways to access nexus.

1. [Nexus REST API](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html)
2. [Aether](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aether)

My requirement is that how can i fetch available list of artifacts from Nexus repository of a specific project and how can i inject older artifact(downloaded) into a local project when it execute.If any one knows how to do this Please share.I can not find any well documented examples.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your questions correctly you are looking at creating a runnable application for your Maven project that includes the dependencies.

This can e.g. for a jar project be done with the Maven Assembly Plugin and the jar-with-dependencies descriptor (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies)